# Streamside plant identification - Oregon

Tags: botany, species-identification

This is in the western cascades forest in Oregon. Leaves are at the ends of branches only, lives mostly in slightly muddy areas next to streams. Produces small black berries.

[image: https://i.imgur.com/sS1cOiL.jpg]

[image]

[image: https://i.imgur.com/kUHeob2.jpg]

Comment: Posts (especially species ID posts) should have *all* photos copied directly into the post and not linked to if possible (i.e., as long as copyright issues allow). This way, we avoid the issue of having an ID question with non-working photo links in the future. Please copy the pics from your "More photos" link directly into your post. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I tried to do that, but it didn't work because they're too large. Is there a way I could get around that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by too large? You mean that they're >2mb when you try to upload directly from your computer? If thats the case, you have to either crop/lower quality or post them somewhere else 1st (which, typically lowers their quality). I simply copied them from your other site and put them here.

Comment: Wow nice way composing the post, showing necessary details.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's a plant in the family *Ribes*, which includes currants.

If it stinks when you crush the leaves, it is probably [Stink Currant, or *Ribes bracteosum*](http://nativeplantspnw.com/stink-currant-ribes-bracteosum/), a plant found in the Pacific Northwest.

> Leaves are large, like maple leaves, sparsely hairy to smooth, with 5 to 7 lobes, stinky when crushed.  Flowers are numerous on mostly erect clusters; with white petals and brownish-purple to greenish-white calyces.  Berries are blue-black with a whitish bloom.

[image]

The leaf and berry are a good match. There are ~150 species, so it's a bit difficult.

It could also be [*Ribes acerifolium*, or Maple-Leaved Currant](https://www.pnwflowers.com/flower/ribes-acerifolium).

> Shrub with spreading branches but no bristles. Leaves maple-like, 1–3 in. across, with 5–7 rounded, finely toothed lobes. Hanging stem of 8–12 greenish flowers, each less than 1/3 in. across with tiny red petals and stamen filaments broad at base. Berry black, coated with bluish powder. Grows from mid elevations to treeline in Cascade and Olympic mountains.

[image]

I could not find a photograph that was not copyrighted. The flower color was pinkish to brownish.

It's not a perfect identification, but it's closer than 'in the ballpark'. If you google "Ribes western Cascades", you'll see what I mean. :)

Comment: Thanks, that gives me what I need. I looked through a fairly comprehensive identification guide of Pacific Northwest wildflowers (had a whole lot more than any book I've seen), and every native flower I've seen was in it except for this one for some reason.

Comment: @Tzacol - Because Murphy's Law... or it's not been identified yet. It does say brownish-purple though, so I woiuldn't rely too heavily on the color of the flower. :)