# What is the name of this plant I found in ROAD HIGHWAY?

Tags: species-identification

Location of the plant is South India,

Plant stem looks like **Banana**.

[image]

Comment: **Down vote**, why so?

Comment: @AScientist thank you for detailed suggestion, can you give me advise where else I can post this pic to get its ID.

Comment: I don't know if any botanist can identify it with only this image. I think you should see this to write a standard identification question. https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/59005/streamside-plant-identification-oregon

Comment: I don't know why @DhanrajKumar your post got down vote. he provided nice quality picture & also I know the **answer** to your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is **Fishtail Palm**, Example picture look like this:

[image]